# IE and CSS flex-box with calc max-height has window resizing issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a use case on a project where there is a modal that uses css `calc` to determine its positioning.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mderrick/7k9zx6c7/

```
.modal {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  top: 2.286rem;
  max-height: calc(100% - 2.286rem * 2);
  max-width: calc(100% - 2.286rem * 2);
}
```

On Chrome it works as desired. I can resize the browser and the modal stays perfectly positioned.

The problem is with IE10 (obviously) where the modal initially loads and it exceeds its `max-height` until I resize the window. This snaps the modal to the correct height but when I make the window shorter, it is stuck at this height unless I resize the windows *width* where it will snap back to it's original (but incorrectly too tall) height. Hopefully the below gifs can help:

**Desired vs IE**

[image: Chrome] [image: Internet Explorer 10]

I welcome all suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: ie10 doesn't fully support flex-box, but your problem occurs in ie11 too

Answer (score 0):

In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property. 
-[Source](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box)

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k9zx6c7/1/) to try out. 
I changed the CSS to reflect what caniuse.com said.

```
.modal {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  top: 2.286rem;
  height: calc(100% - 2.286rem * 2);
  max-height: calc(100% - 2.286rem * 2);
  max-width: calc(100% - 2.286rem * 2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I need it to be `max-height` as the modal shouldn't always fill the entire screen if it needn't. The first thing I did was try it with height and although it works almost, its not quite what I need. I will update my questions to be more explicit.